# Using Graph# for drawing graph

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, draw

I want to draw a graph like the one i've attached here:

[image]

I dont wanna re invent the wheel and start to draw circles and so on, so i googled for libraries and what i found is Graph#. Unfortunately there is no documentation/tutorial, so i'm a little confused that is this what i need or not!

What I need is to be able to choose colors for vertexes, set font and size, thickness of edges and distance from the root. Anyone can help me? Any example of graph#? any other library?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the GraphX library based on Graph# (http://graphx.codeplex.com)
Although some modifications will be needed to do so such as templates change or algorithm customizations. If you have any questions please feel free to ask in the Discussions page on the site. Cheers.